# Biblatex: field "series" has wrong format

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

This is my first attempt to create my own style for Biblatex and Biber. I used chicago-authordate as a starting point, because it matches many of my requirements. By drawing from information found here, I was able to adjust most of the style to my requirements. Here is my last one, which I cannot solve. If the cited text is from a series, this information should be added as follows:

> Lohndal, Terje. 2007. On the structure and development of nominal phrases in Norwegian. In 
>           Nominal Determination. Typology, Context Constraints, and Historical Emergence 
>           [Studies in Language Companion Series 89], Elisabeth Stark, Elizabeth Leiss & Werner 
>           Abraham (eds), 285-308. Amsterdam: John Benjamins.

i.e. the series should be in square brackets as a title followed by the word "Series" followed by the series number.

I adjusted the definition \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection} as follows:

```
\iffieldundef{series}
{}%
{\space%
\blx@bibopenbracket%
\printfield{series}%
\ Series%
\printfield[sernum]{number}%
\blx@bibclosebracket}%
```

Everything else works out nicely, but there is a comma after the opening square bracket:

> [, Studies in Language Companion Series 89]

Since the comma is within the square bracket, it has to come from the definition of "series" to the best of my understanding. I already tried to eliminate the comma with \DeclareSourcemap. I seem to apply the function correctly, since I can remove other characters but not the comma. I just don't know where it comes from.

Here's what the relevant part of my file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=myownstyle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite[][]{Lohndal:OnTheStructure:2007}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to have confused the punctuation tracker. Try if it works if you use `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket` and replace the `\space` by `\setunit{\addspace}` or `\setunit*{\addspace}`.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike, that worked like a charme. For the records, I had to put the space and the bracket into the same unit:
\setunit{\addspace\bibopenbracket}. @UlrikeFischer: how can I credit you for the answer?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `\mkbibbrackets`?

Comment: @Bernard: because I'm a beginner ;-) I looked it up now and it's a good idea. I will use it, if I need the series in more than one source, for the moment I leave it as described above.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have confused the punctuation tracker. Try if it works if you use `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket` and replace the `\space` by `\setunit{\addspace}` or `\setunit*{\addspace}`. The `\setunit{\addspace\bibopenbracket}` that you mention in your comment looks a bit dubious but without minimal example I can't test why you think that you need it.